# Accessing Models on Every Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I'm creating a menu on every page, in the `_Layout.cshtml` where i want to display sub-menus of the Entity items. For example:

> **Locations:**
>   Sydney
>   Melbourne
>   Camberra

I have though about creating a `BaseController` inheriting from `Controller` and overriding the `View()` method to pass the lists to the views.

But not sure, if doing so would override the passed parameters from the `View` in my other Controllers.

And ideally i wouldn't want to repeat the same code in every CRUD method etc.

Any ideas on the best way to achieve what i'm looking for?

Comment: You should user partial view and a controller action which would populate the model and pass it to the partial view. Then use RenderAction method of to render the partial view in layout page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Chetan Ranpariya, put me on the right path.

I create a new `Controller` with a new action `LocationMenu` passing my Data in a `ViewModel` then using `@Html.RenderAction("LocationMenu", "Menu")`

Perfect, thank you.

Comment: It would be much better if you could post the actual code you ended up using than describing the steps

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, that's as far as I've gotten. I'm still having issues i use Repository Pattern and can't call an Async action so having to re-work it ATM.